# Do "capture all" servlet filters configured inside deploys wars capture all requests, or only those for the application contained in that war?

Tags: rest, web.xml, servlet-filters, apache-tomee

I am working on a REST application that is using Servlet filters to perform some validations.

The application consists of 6 deployed services, that are deployed as war files. The application is deployed in an Apache TomEE webserver (1.7.3). The application uses the JAX-RS API 2.0.

The URLs of endpoints in each of the webapps follow the same pattern.

They all follow the pattern:

```
/<2 letter application identifier>-ws-rest/<endpoint name part>/<endpoint name part>
```

For example:

```
/cd-ws-rest/install/data
/af-ws-rest/retrieve/user/information
```

I have the servlet filter configured as follows in the web.xml (the file located at `APACHE_TOMEE/conf/web.xml`):

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.company.LoggingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>LoggingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

This filter captures all requests (regardless of which deployed war the request is for). In other words, requests to all endpoints (regardless of which of the wars that endpoints exists in) are captured by this filter.

I would like to change the application so that instead of configuring the filter in the TomEE web.xml, I would like to configure it in a web.xml file that is packaged within a war(s). This will make deployment easier, as the person deploying the application will not have to change the web.xml in TomEE.

I plan to add a web.xml inside each war, at the path

```
<module name>/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
```

But I am not sure how a filter configured inside a deployed war behaves. If I add a  filter who's url-pattern is "/*", will that filter only capture requests for that service or for all requests for all deployed wars?

Comment: Which version of TomEE are you using? please edit the OP and add this information.

Comment: If the latter were true, that would be a huge security breach.

Comment: @BalusC could you please explain your comment a little more, thanks!

Comment: Imagine one server serving various webapps from independent users (e.g. shared hosting). If a filter from one webapp could hook on requests to other webapps, then it could read and manipulate everything in other webapps. Surely this is not permitted.

Comment: "I have the servlet filter configured as follows in the web.xml (the file located at APACHE_TOMEE/conf/web.xml)" --
This is non-standard and will only work on servers that use Tomcat as their web container (as TomEE obviously does). Putting the filter info in each war is the way to go for what you want.
IMHO there ought to be a *standard* way to specify global filters, but it's 2019 and there still isn't.

Answer (score 2):

A slash star mapping will make the filter apply to all requests to the web application where the filter was defined only.

According to the servlet 3.0 spec section 6.2.1:

> Only one instance per <filter> declaration in the deployment descriptor is
>   instantiated per JVM of the container. The container provides the filter config as declared in the filter’s deployment descriptor, the reference to the ServletContext for the Web application, and the set of initialization parameters.

And section 6.2.4:

> Filters can be associated with groups of servlets and static content using the <urlpattern>
>   style of filter mapping:
>   Here the Logging Filter is applied to all the servlets and static content pages in the Web application, because every request URI matches the ‘/*’ URL pattern.

There might be server specific solutions that might allow to apply a filter to all requests made to all applications, but the default servlet spec defined behavior is to apply the filter to requests in the application where it was defined.